# All Windows 11 nics bridged to windows qemu

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-11, qemu

how can i bridge all network interfaces from my windows-11 install to the guest system???? I use the windows qemu client.

For now use this command with 1 nic in guest, but that do not help me.

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -drive file=C:\vm\pfsense.img -m 8000 -net nic -net user
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to SU. Kudos for trying... I'd rather use VirtulaBox as a VM platform on Windows, as it's much more widely used and far better documented solution.

Comment: Ok maybe i try another software. Bridged mode in virtual box did not work for my pfsense virtual guest system setup.

Comment: OK. Just installed following [these instructions](https://getlabsdone.com/how-to-install-pfsense-on-virtualbox/). The WAN port got an IP address from my DHCP server and I can successfully ping Google DNS, so bridging per se does work.

Comment: yeah but i have a wan adpter a lan adapter and a wlan adapter all in a specific net. and pfsense as guest system should manage it to route everything and dhcp my lan and wlan network. Not just Internet.

Comment: Of course, that's the whole point of router, different interfaces in different networks :-) I only tested that one thing - does bridged interface work, and on my system it does. Maybe you could [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777896/edit) your question to give more details of the situation. What exactly work, what fails and how, how things should work, configuration files etc. That'll help pinpointing the failure.

Comment: i just can't get into the lan side of the network or web configurator. the connection from the dhcp from the guest system to the lan adapter on host does not work. with dhcp or static config.

Comment: Again, please edit the question to clarify. I just tested, enabled my Wi-Fi adapter and connected it to my phone hotspot. I bridged PFSense LAN interface to it and gave it IP in appropriate range. I also connected another laptop to my phone hotspot and successfully pinged the PFSense LAN interface => I have now 2 working bridged interfaces on PFSense VM running on VBox. Without knowing the physical connectivity and configurations it's really difficult to guess where the problem might be. As I said, I'm just testing bridged interfaces on VBox VM as you said those didn't work.

Comment: i switched now back to virtrualbox and set the virtual interfaces to bridge mode with the specific adapter i want to use.